# Angular Frontend - How do I change a value I got from backend in frontend

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript

I recently started Angular and I've been stuck on this single problem.

So when the frontend loads a page, it performs a GET and fetches the following values:

```
getAll(fetch_id: string): Subject<Element[]> {
this.dataSource.getData(fetch_id).subscribe((elements) => {
  this.elements = elements.map((element) => ({
    id: element.element_id.toString(),
    name: element.element_name,
    fetch_method: element.fetch_method_id,
    created: element.created_at,
  }));
  this.elements$.next(this.elements);
});
return this.elements$;
```

My HTML is displaying like this:

```
<td
    class="pointer"
    mat-cell
    *matCellDef="let element"
    [routerLink]="getFetchUrl(element)"
  >
    {{ element.fetch_method }}
  </td>
```

My issue is: the *fetch_method* wil either return 1,2 or 3, which I have to represent differently in the Frontend part (if 1, the frontend must display "Automatic", if 2, it must display "Manual", if 3, it must display "Both").

Currently, my Frontend only displays 1,2 or 3.

I tried searching if I could insert and IF-ELSE statament somewhere but found nothing that could help. I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, based on the value of element.fetch_method, we need to display 1,2 or BOTH ?

Comment: The backend API will return me 1,2 or 3. Based on the value that returns, the front end part must show "Automatic", "Manual" or "Both".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **enum** like this:

**ts file:**

```
export enum fetchMethodEnum {
  Automatic = 1,
  Manual = 2,
  Both = 3,
}
```

you can create separate file for enum or add in ts file before `@component`

and in class bind the enum to a variable:

```
fetchMethod = fetchMethodEnum;
```

**html file:**

```
  <td  class="pointer" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
       [routerLink]="getFetchUrl(element)"
  >
    {{ fetchMethod[element.fetch_method] }}
```

based on `element.fetch_method` id is shown enums.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Pretty helpful method :) Just got another question. I implemented the enum part in my ts file instead of a separate. When I try to call fetchMethod in my HTML, it causes a compile error: "Property 'fetchMethod' does not exist on type 'ElementViewComponent' (my HTML file)". Do I need to import it somewhere?

Comment: @user17447487 I forgot to say that, you need to bind enum to a variable so add `fetchMethod = fetchMethod;` (or chose better variable name :) ) in your class in ts file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Got it working. Voted your response up, but said I don't have enough rep (I'm new to this website), but it was saved. Thank you for the help nonetheless :)